# How to get access to tracking Information in Ionic projects?

Tags: google-maps, ionic-framework

How to get access to tracking Information in Ionic ?

I want to show some information over map

```
-) direction from A to B
-) pointer of device
-) real time tracking
-) speed, and acceleration information.
```

Comment: try geolocation plugin

Comment: @Iris_geek Thanks. Give it an answer to approve it.

Comment: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-geolocation/#methods. Check the documentation and try it out. I used the same for location tracking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @iris-geek said, you had to use [geolocation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-geolocation/#methods) of Cordova, I used it was pretty good and useful. Ionic had Cordova has good documentation about.